# How can I do for in loop in async function binded to Telethon?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, telethon, python-asyncio

I want to get access to dialogs and messages in Telethon in my async def function binded to NewMessage event with pattern 'get_data'. Overall, binding works and I get 'hi' response in STDOUT, but for loop not I don't get 'hi2' response and later code is not executed. I'm not sure if I understand asynchrous theory, but we will see.

I tried few asyncio functions (like sleep, wait), moving my client.start() from before to after event binding, doing function with for-in loops outside and calling it with await inside async def and nothing works.

```py
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

print('1')
@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='get_data'))
async def get_data(event):
    await print('hi')
    print(client.iter_dialogs())
    for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
        print('hi2')
        print(dialog.name)

        for message in client.iter_messages(dialog.id, reverse=True):
            entity = client.get_entity(message.sender_id)
            print('{0} {1}'.format(entity.first_name, entity.last_name), ':', message.text)
    await event.respond('Got data!')

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

I want for-in loops to be executed without messing out, since I want to expand this code more. I want them to be executed in /correct/ manner - so, when I get_data will be called I will get them executed like normal program without doing asynchrously inside (so, this why I wanted do await).

Maybe my attempts are fine but I am not using correctly Telethon?

Comment: *Always* enable `logging` when developing: `import logging; logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `for ... iter_messages` with `async for ... iter_messages` and same for iter_dialogs. Currently you're not running the async code. Edit: and don't await the print()

Comment: Ah, thanks... My stupidy. Everything seems working :| I overcomplicated that.